# How to resolve invalid connect parameters in jms?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ to transfer data objects from client to server by using following client uri :

```
ssl://X.X.X.X:61616?useKeepAlive=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000&wireFormat.cacheEnabled=false&wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=true
```

By using the above uri am getting the following exception when I start the application :

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {useKeepAlive=false}
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:258)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:230)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:178)
        at com.infomindz.esdms.messaging.agent.job.handler.MessageQueueLocator.getSecureManagementJmsSession(MessageQueueLocator.java:991)
        at com.infomindz.esdms.messaging.agent.job.handler.MessageQueueLocator.sendMessageToSEMQueue(MessageQueueLocator.java:902)
        at com.infomindz.esdms.messaging.agent.job.MediaDriverStatusJob.saveAndSendPropertyDetails(Unknown Source)
        at com.infomindz.esdms.messaging.agent.job.MediaDriverStatusJob.checkInitFile(Unknown Source)
        at com.infomindz.esdms.messaging.agent.job.MediaDriverStatusJob.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {useKeepAlive=false}
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:144)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:51)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:80)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:243)
```

How do I resolve this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Transport parameters must be prefixed with "transport." in the url; so you need to do it like this :

```
ssl://X.X.X.X:61616?transport.useKeepAlive=false
```

See [this page](http://activemq.apache.org/ssl-transport-reference.html).

Comment: In my case the prefixed attribute was 'broker' but this one fixed it, thx

Comment: I downvoted.  (1) It didn't work for me (2) There's no explanation of how it should be working, so I don't know why it didn't work (3) There's no link or quote of any other document or reference where more knowledge or explanation is available